# How to stop .net-core from continuously adding folders when building

Tags: visual-studio, azure, .net-core, botframework, azure-web-app-service

Every time I build my .NET Core project, it adds a deeper folder containing the `.csproj` file in `\bin\release`. The result is the following folder structure:

```
D:\home>
D:\home\site>
D:\home\site\repository>
D:\home\site\repository\bin>
D:\home\site\repository\bin\Release>
D:\home\site\repository\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1>
D:\home\site\repository\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin>
D:\home\site\repository\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\Release>
D:\home\site\repository\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1>
D:\home\site\repository\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin>
D:\home\site\repository\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\Release>
D:\home\site\repository\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1>
D:\home\site\repository\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin>
D:\home\site\repository\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\bin\Release>
```

This keeps on growing when more builds are executed.

In Visual Studio, cleaning and rebuilding helps solve it. After a few builds the filename becomes too long, raising an error when trying to run the application.

At first, it did not really matter, but when deploying the WebApp-Bot to Azure, the same happens. The problem is that I have no option to remove the excessive files from the server. Which is why I need to stop it from happening at all.

The `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <UserSecretsId>SOME_USER_SECRETS_ID</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Remove="%2a%2a\**" />
    <Content Remove="%2a%2a\**" />
    <EmbeddedResource Remove="%2a%2a\**" />
    <None Remove="%2a%2a\**" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Gremlin.Net" Version="3.4.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis" Version="4.4.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs" Version="4.4.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core" Version="4.4.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Recognizers.Text.DataTypes.TimexExpression" Version="1.1.6" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Import Project="PostDeployScripts\IncludeSources.targets" Condition="Exists('PostDeployScripts\IncludeSources.targets')" />
  <Import Project="..\PostDeployScripts\IncludeSources.targets" Condition="Exists('..\PostDeployScripts\IncludeSources.targets')" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="%2a%2a\%2a.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="bin\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ProjectExtensions><VisualStudio><UserProperties Properties_4launchSettings_1json__JSONSchema="" /></VisualStudio></ProjectExtensions>

</Project>
```

The `includesources.targets`, which I see now has the `always` flag:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Update="**\*.cs">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Compile>
    <None Include="**\*.csproj" >
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="PostDeployScripts\*.*" >
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I would like to know why this happens and how to stop it, all help is welcome.

Comment: Can you share your csproj? Or can you recreate this in a minimal project?

Comment: Added the file to the post, most of it is as it was in the Webapp-Bot example from Microsoft

Comment: I have a feeling that it's this part: `<ItemGroup><Folder Include="bin\" /></ItemGroup>` which might be telling MSBuild to include the bin directory, which already contains the release directory, which will then contain another bin directory, which will.... if you catch my drift

Comment: What does `IncludeSources.targets` contain?

Comment: @JamieTaylor `<Folder>` items only tell VS to display the folder even if it is empty.

Comment: @MartinUllrich you're right, of course. Apologies for the confusion.

Comment: Added the includesources.targets file, which i see has the property CopyToOutputDirectory set as Always.... What is a correct value here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `includesources.targets` file has this little gem in it:

```
<Compile Update="**\*.cs">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</Compile>
```

Which would, if I understand correctly, cause the `.cs` files to be copied to your output folder. The next time a build is triggered, these files will probably also be compiled, creating a new `bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1` from that location.

I'm not entirely sure what the targets file is there for, but I am pretty sure it's causing this issue. Try removing the file and the references to it from your `.csproj`, rebuild your project and see if you can deploy the bot.